# Get Method from Groovy method closure

Tags: reflection, groovy

In groovy the `.&` operator converts a method in a closure. In Java using the reflection Method object, one can get the method name, parameters names and types. Is there a way to get all the method reflection information from the closure? I'm only able to get the parameter types so far (via `closure.parameterTypes`)

Comment: No you can't. You'd need to use reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a closure from a Method, you are not really linking a `java.lang.Method` but only a name: If you have differents methods with the same name, but differents parameters, it will work.

When you call the closure with parameters, groovy try to lookup the best method which fit the parameters (as usual in Groovy).

So, you can't get a `Method` from a closure, but you can get the name :

```
def closure = instance.@myMethod
assert "myMethod" == closure.method
```

You can then find all possible methods from the `owner` class:

```
def methods = closure.owner.metaClass.respondsTo(closure.owner, closure.method)
```

Comment: does groovy compiler support the -parameters option?

Comment: `instance.@myMethod` --> don't you mean `instance.&myMethod` ?

Answer (score 2):

Not directly from the `Closure`, but you can get the `Method` *from* the `Closure`:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method

class Person {
    def firstName
    def lastName

    def getFullName() {
        "$firstName $lastName"
    }
}

Person person = new Person(firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe')
Closure closure = person.&getFullName
Method method = closure.owner.class.getMethod('getFullName')

assert person.fullName == closure()
assert person.fullName == method.invoke(person)
```

The .& operator returns a [MethodClosure](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/MethodClosure.html), which maintains a reference to the instance in the `owner` property. So you can go from there, to the `Class`, and then finally to the `Method`.